# Getting each word from long list in python

Tags: python, string, list

So I have this list that looks like this:

```
['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
['Five', 'Six', 'Seven']
```

so, a list with 2 elements (each of the above rows is a specific element of the list),    `lst =  [['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'], ['Five', 'Six', 'Seven']]`

My question is how to extract each word above as a string, to get for example two string arrays like

```
'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'
'Five', 'Six', 'Seven'
```

Until now I thought of converting it all into a string, and then splitting it. Here is my code:

```
a = str(list)
c = a.translate(None, '[]\'\'')   #to remove the ' ' and [ ]
c.split() #split here doesn't seem to be doing anything 
print c
```

and the result is one big string "One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven"

It should be something really simple, but im new to prog, and can't seem to find an angle to it. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? You already have the words in lists, what precisely do you mean by *"string arrays"*? Do you just want e.g. `['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'] + ['Five', 'Six', 'Seven']`?

Comment: What do you mean by "string arrays"? Are you specifically referring to the data type found in the `array` module, or are you just using the term interchangeably with `list` to mean "the builtin data type Python uses to represent an ordered sequence of items"? Or something else?

Comment: forget the "string arrays". how can i get each word specifically? i mean to have a variable myString for example that contains one of the numbers above

Comment: So, indexing? `myString = myList[0][3] #gets the fourth item in the first sublist`?

Comment: yea, apparently that did it....as i said, i am new to programming...thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edit 1***

I think you have a list of lists, and are trying to join the inner lists. If that is the case, try this:

```
>>> l = [['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'], ['Five', 'Six', 'Seven']]
>>> [', '.join(x) for x in l]
['One, Two, Three, Four', 'Five, Six, Seven']
```

In case you want to access individual elements within the list, say `"Six"`, you can access it using the respective indexes. Read more about [them on the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

```
>>> l[1][1]
'Six'
```

***Original Answer***

I think you are looking for the str.join method

```
>>> ', '.join(['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'])
'One, Two, Three, Four'
>>> ', '.join(['Five', 'Six', 'Seven'])
'Five, Six, Seven'
```

Comment: i tried this, but the error shows: sqeuence item 0: expected string, list found

Comment: yep, it works now perfectly! apparently i could index it like the comment at my question, but your way works also nice!! thnx :)

Answer (score 1):

Split isn't doing anything because you aren't doing anything with it. You need `"c ="` to actually assign the result of the split to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use itertools like so. Basically, the chain function unpacks your nested list into a single iterator which you can then join with standard string methods.

```
your_list = [['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'], ['Five', 'Six', 'Seven']]

import itertools

string = ", ".join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(your_list))
print string
```

Comment: Please avoid using `from foo import *` in code examples. It is bad style and encourages code smells.

Comment: I mean, if you're versed in documentation, you don't really need to do that. You know where it's coming from and it's not really a code smell.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is just not true. Do you know every function within the standard API? What about other libraries you may have imported?